# How to calculate time(in Hours) from selected time(Hours) to given duration

Tags: swift

For eg, if I have selected Time: 3pm and the number of hours: 5 hours, then get (8pm) as answer"

Comment: Are you using dates or just 12h am/pm selection regardless of the calendar dates? Note that some dates don't have 24 hours. So what would be the result if a specific date ends at 11pm when the user adds 8 hours 11pm or 12am?

Comment: Using 12h am/pm regardless of the calender dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let date = calendar.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 5, to: Date())
or
let date = calendar.date(byAdding: . minute, value: 330, to: Date())
```

> Now you can get hour

```
let comp = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: date)
let hour = comp.hour
let minute = comp.minute

print(hour)// This is your answer.
```

Comment: let date = calendar.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 5.30, to: Date())
then date = nil

Comment: value is an Int type

Comment: But I have Int as well as Float value, in that case what I can do.

Comment: you can do it using minutes for 5.30 hour. let date = calendar.date(byAdding: . minute, value: 330, to: Date())